# Can you store and retrieve entire documents in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm building a web-app where the user can search for documents using keywords. I've used the ingest plug-in in elasticsearch to index documents to make searching straightforward. However I also want to add the option of downloading the original document after the search is completed. Since I process the document through the ingest pipeline and its contents are only stored as plaintext, I can't think of a way to retrieve the original document so that it can be downloaded.

Can elasicsearch be used for this function? Or should I be using something else? If so, what? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can upload to elastic a full text document and you'll be able to retrieve only the message part to the user. I implemented something similar. It is actually very simple.

You should add as a tag the name of the document and the context in the message. the query would be pretty straight forward as well

p.s.

I would give more information but your question was a bit broad. In my case the code which fetch the information from Elastic was written in C# but you can do it with lot of other languages.